# COTURN peerJS connectivity issue

Tags: android, webrtc, peerjs, turn, coturn

I've set up a COTURN server for my Android app that utilizes peer.js for webRTC voice communication (isVideoCall is always false in the following code.)
While testing with the TURN server URL using https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/, there are no apparent issues. However, in the actual application, I'm encountering intermittent connectivity problems.

Most of the time, the call fails with neither party being able to hear anything. And in successful calls, the initial voice only comes after a 3-6 seconds delay.

Here are some details about the setup:

=> Both clients are connected to Wi-Fi networks.

=>The COTURN server is running on a server with 1GB RAM and a single-core shared CPU. (Currently, my app has only less than 2k active users.)

=>Client setup - PeerJS running on android webview.

=>Firewall rules have been configured to allow traffic on ports 443 and 3478.

This is my client-side code:

```
let localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video");
let remoteVideo = document.getElementById("remote-video");
let myCall = undefined; 

remoteVideo.style.opacity = 0.0;

let peer;
var videoConstraints = false;
var constraints = { audio: false, video: false };

function init(userId, peerPath, peerKey, isVideoCall, turnPwd1, turnPwd2) {
  if (isVideoCall === "true") {
    videoConstraints = {
      width: { ideal: 1280, max: 1280, min: 640 },
      height: { ideal: 720, max: 720, min: 480 },
      facingMode: "user", // Force front camera
      frameRate: { ideal: 24, max: 24, min: 15 },
    };
  } else videoConstraints = false;

  let audioConstraints = {
    channelCount: 1,
    sampleRate: 8000, //16000,
    sampleSize: 8, //16,
    volume: 1,
    latency: 0.003,
    echoCancellation: true,
    noiseSuppression: true,
    autoGainControl: true,
  };
  constraints = { audio: audioConstraints, video: videoConstraints };

  peer = new Peer(userId, {
    //production
    host: "myappurl.com",
    port: 443,
    secure: true,
    path: peerPath,
    proxied: true,
    key: peerKey,

    config: {
      iceServers: [
        {
          url: "turn:turn.myappurl.com:3478",
          username: "foo",
          credential: turnPwd1,
        },
        {
          url: "turn:turn.myappurl.com:443",//<= ChatGPT suggested to use turns scheme instead of turn, I haven't tried it yet.
          username: "bar",
          credential: turnPwd1,
        },
        { url: "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302" },
        { url: "stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302" },
      ],
    },
  });

  peer.on("open", () => {
    Android.onPeerConnected();
  });

  peer.on("error", (err) => {
    Android.onError();
    Android.logEvent("onError: " + err);
  });
  peer.on("disconnected", () => {
    // peer.reconnect() //may crash the server
    Android.onDisconnect();
  });
  listen();
}
let localStream;
function listen() {
  peer.on("call", (call) => {
    myCall = call;
    navigator.mediaDevices
      .getUserMedia(constraints)
      .then(function (stream) {
        localVideo.srcObject = stream;
        localStream = stream;
        call.answer(stream, {
          sdpTransform: transformSdp,
        });
        call.on("stream", (rStream) => {
          Android.onPeerStream();
          remoteVideo.srcObject = rStream;
        });
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        Android.logEvent("getUserMedia error: " + err);
      });
  });
}

function startCall(otherUserId) {
  navigator.mediaDevices
    .getUserMedia(constraints)
    .then(function (stream) {
      localVideo.srcObject = stream;
      localStream = stream;
      const call = peer.call(otherUserId, stream, {
        sdpTransform: transformSdp,
      });
      call.on("stream", (rStream) => {
        Android.onPeerStream();
        remoteVideo.srcObject = rStream;
      });
      myCall = call;
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      Android.logEvent("getUserMedia error: " + err);
    });
}


function destroyPeer() {
  if (myCall) myCall.close();
  peer.destroy();
  Android.logEvent("destroying peer");
}

function transformSdp(sdp) {
  var splitArray = sdp.split("\n");
  for (let i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {
    if (splitArray[i].startsWith("a=fmtp:111")) {
      //add dtx param to opus
      sdp = sdp.replace(splitArray[i], splitArray[i].concat(";usedtx=1"));
      break;
    }
  }
  //Android.logEvent(sdp);
  //sdp=setMediaBitrates(sdp)
  return sdp;
}

function setMediaBitrates(sdp) {
  return setMediaBitrate(setMediaBitrate(sdp, "video", 800), "audio", 48);
}

function setMediaBitrate(sdp, media, bitrate) {
  var lines = sdp.split("\n");
  var line = -1;
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    if (lines[i].indexOf("m=" + media) === 0) {
      line = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (line === -1) {
    console.debug("Could not find the m line for", media);
    return sdp;
  }
  console.debug("Found the m line for", media, "at line", line);

  // Pass the m line
  line++;

  // Skip i and c lines
  while (lines[line].indexOf("i=") === 0 || lines[line].indexOf("c=") === 0) {
    line++;
  }

  // If we're on a b line, replace it
  if (lines[line].indexOf("b") === 0) {
    console.debug("Replaced b line at line", line);
    lines[line] = "b=AS:" + bitrate;
    return lines.join("\n");
  }

  // Add a new b line
  console.debug("Adding new b line before line", line);
  var newLines = lines.slice(0, line);
  newLines.push("b=AS:" + bitrate);
  newLines = newLines.concat(lines.slice(line, lines.length));
  return newLines.join("\n");
}
```

Could you please provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: "Most of the time, the call fails with neither party being able to hear anything. And in successful calls, the initial voice only comes after a 3-6 seconds delay." This may mean that the unsuccessful cases are timing out due to a slow ICE negotiation. I would suggest to simplify the setup and only use one TURN URL, then take traces on the TURN host to verify the STUN activity. You could also try setting `iceTransportPolicy` to "relay" to ensure both clients are forced through TURN, and not for example one goes via coturn and the other uses public Internet on coturn's relay side.

Comment: getting this error from Chromium, [ERROR:socket_manager.cc(141)] Failed to resolve address for turn.myappurl.com., errorcode: -105

Comment: I get the above error even if I use a third-party turn server.

Comment: I'd recommend continuing the troubleshooting against your TURN server, just starting with simplifying things (only 1 TURN URL in the configuration, iceTransportPolicy set to 'relay') and taking traces on both the browser host and TURN server host. That will give you a lot of information on each single packet (STUN and RTP) exchanged, and a good understanding of what's going on.

Comment: I reviewed the ```/var/log/syslog``` file on my server, I've noticed a significant number of errors similar to the ones below,
```
2024-03-03T00:47:29.352203+00:00 localhost turnserver: 751915: : ERROR: session 000000000000089411: TLS/TCP socket error: Connection reset by peer 45.79.168.172:56715

2024-03-05T05:24:58.278198+00:00 localhost turnserver: 941364: : ERROR: session 001000000000113292: TLS/TCP socket error: Broken pipe 206.81.1.63:40808
```
The IP addresses in these errors seem owned by Linode and DIGITALOCEAN-ASN. Linode is my server provider. Why Digitalocean is there.